# Textures on 3d models appear very dark in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I have a simple model that I intend to use within a Libgdx application. Unfortunately, as the title suggests, when I do so, the textures on that model appear very dark.

[Model within Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyxuC.png)

I am rendering simple terrain beneath the models, which appears with appropriate brightness, implying the issue lies with the properties of the imported models rather than the Libgdx environment. Even so, I have tried using ambient lighting to illuminate the models, directional lights pointing directly at the imported models, and also placing a point light directly above them, all of which had no effect on the brightness of the rendered textures.

[Model within Libgdx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrrDw.png)

Though the issue appears to be with the textures on the models, the same model renders correctly within 3D Viewer, implying that this may not be the case. However, as well as within Libgdx, the model also appears almost completely black within the preview tool of the Fbx-conv application.

[Model within Fbx-Conv application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqGmX.png)

Therefore, it seems probable that the issue arises during the conversion process, so I have attached the G3DJ output file (though I omitted the vertex and index info to reduce the length of this post) from the conversion tool. I did check the file, but I did not see any obvious sources of tint introduced during the process that converts an Fbx file into a G3DB file.

```
{
"version": [  0,   1], 
"id": "", 
"meshes": [
            {
        "attributes": ["POSITION", "NORMAL", "TEXCOORD0"], 
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"materials": [
    {
        "id": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_01", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.215861,  0.215861,  0.215861], 
        "emissive": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "opacity":  1.000000, 
        "specular": [ 0.215861,  0.215861,  0.215861], 
        "shininess":  20.000000, 
        "textures": [
            {
                "id": "base_color_texture", 
                "filename": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_01_BaseColor.png", 
                "type": "DIFFUSE"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_02", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.215861,  0.215861,  0.215861], 
        "emissive": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "opacity":  1.000000, 
        "specular": [ 0.215861,  0.215861,  0.215861], 
        "shininess":  20.000000, 
        "textures": [
            {
                "id": "base_color_texture", 
                "filename": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_02_BaseColor.png", 
                "type": "DIFFUSE"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_03", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.215861,  0.215861,  0.215861], 
        "emissive": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "opacity":  1.000000, 
        "specular": [ 0.215861,  0.215861,  0.215861], 
        "shininess":  20.000000, 
        "textures": [
            {
                "id": "base_color_texture", 
                "filename": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_03_BaseColor.png", 
                "type": "DIFFUSE"
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"nodes": [
    {
        "id": "Quarry", 
        "rotation": [-0.707107,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107], 
        "scale": [ 100.000000,  100.000000,  100.000000], 
        "parts": [
            {
                "meshpartid": "Feature.002_part3", 
                "materialid": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_01", 
                "uvMapping": [[]]
            }, 
            {
                "meshpartid": "Feature.002_part2", 
                "materialid": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_02", 
                "uvMapping": [[]]
            }, 
            {
                "meshpartid": "Feature.002_part1", 
                "materialid": "MI_MH_02_Atlas_03", 
                "uvMapping": [[]]
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"animations": []
```

}

I have seen a few similar questions on the internet; these, however, related to missing textures, rather than textures that were present but - for some reason - heavily tinted, and therefore did not help me. Does anybody have any experience with textures appearing darker than they should? If so any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and in my case the texture wasn't rendering because the dimensions of the texture file were not a power of two (As explaind in [LibGDX's documentation](https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/3d/importing-blender-models-in-libgdx#troubleshooting-black-textures), weird that they chose to document this issue instead of fixing it).

I changed the size of the texture in Blender using the *Python Console* view (Shift+F4) like so: `bpy.data.images["ImageName"].scale(x, y)`.
There's also an option to resize it in the *Image Editor* view but it didn't work for some reason.

Hope that hellps.